# Ghostscript: How to add a white margin

Tags: ghostscript

at the moment I am trying to add a white margin to an A1 pdf using ghostscript. I want to print it via "flyeralarm.de"  and they tell me to have a white margin of .6 cm around the whole document. So instead of 84.0 times 59.4 cm it would be 84.6 times 60 cm. I am pretty New to ghostscript and I could not find anything helpful with Google. Can you help me?

Sincerely

Slin